# Error: Unhandled Exceptions when trying to deploy / (re)publish ShinyApps.io

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

I have a shiny app that depends on a GitHub package.  I recently updated the GitHub package, so I want to republish the shiny app as well.  I have made no changes to the shiny app code at all, and it runs without error in RStudio.  But, when I go to republish it, I get these messages in the Deploy tab of RStudio.

```
Preparing to deploy document...DONE
Uploading bundle for document: 96244...DONE
Deploying bundle: 426681 for document: 96244 ...
Waiting for task: 180459152
  building: Parsing manifest
  building: Building image: 419646
  building: Building package: xtable
################################ Begin Task Log ################################ 
################################# End Task Log ################################# 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 180459153 error: Unhandled Exception: HTTP 599: Connection closed
Execution halted
```

I am running the latest versions of R (3.2.5) and RStudio (0.99.893) on Windows 7, and I made sure all the packages have been updated.

I searched around for folks reporting similar errors (and solutions) and found didn't find anything helpful.

I'd appreciate any tips.

Links:

- [Shiny app](https://github.com/JVAdams/LW1949) - if it says "*Last modified: 7 January 2016*", it's still the old version that I'm trying to replace.
- [Code for shiny app](https://github.com/JVAdams/LW1949/blob/master/inst/DemoApp/LW1949Interactive.Rmd)
- [GitHub package](https://github.com/JVAdams/LW1949)

Comment: You'll have better luck asking here, I think: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/shinyapps-users

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you update to **R 3.2.5**? It seems `shinyapps.io` is not ready for this.

I had these errors yesterday. Roll back to 3.2.4 and it will work.

**Note this is confirmed in  [shinyapps forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shinyapps-users/lpXQ1XOQhkc)**:

> "Is it at all possible that you are running with R version 3.2.5?  If
>   so, downgrading to 3.2.4 should fix this issue.  The error message
>   should be saying something like: shinyapps.io doesn't support this
>   version of R yet."

Comment: *Confirmed.*  After I rolled back to 3.2.4, I was able to deploy the shiny app.  I agree that a more informative error message would have been nice.  Would have saved me a few hours.

Comment: I feel you. Sometimes the problem isn't in your code! I will be checking the forum next time when something weird crops up.